# Generate xUnit test results in .json format

Tags: dotnet-test

Currently, I'm running a set of `xUnit` test using the following command:

```
dotnet test --filter TestType=$testType --logger trx
```

Is there a way to generate results in json format? Something like `--logger json`?

Thank you.